# Selecting certain subjects and making graphs

Tags: r, plot

With R, I would have two questions:

1. How do I select all the subjects that have both "stomachache" and "reflux"?
2. I would like to make a band plot with the percentage of subjects that have both "stomachache" and "reflux".

I will leave you an example of the dataset I have available

| Subject_ID | event | Week | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A21 | stomachache | 23 | 3 |
| A21 | eating disorder | 10 | 2 |
| A21 | reflux | 21 | 1 |
| A22 | stomachache | 15 | 2 |
| A22 | muscle pain | 9 | 2 |
| A23 | stomachache | 21 | 1 |
| A23 | reflux | 12 | 3 |
| A24 | eating disorder | 16 | 2 |

This is an example of the plot I'd like to reproduce

[image]

Comment: please show a example of your desired output for the "band plot"

Comment: I've just added an ideal plot

Comment: I still have no clue how you can visualize your data in this kind of plot.

Comment: I am just interested in the percentage of subjects that have both Reflux and Stomachache, I have no clear idea of how to represent it. I've added two columns to the data set in order to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question

```
> aggregate(. ~ event, df, c, subset = event %in% c("stomachache", "reflux"))
        event    Subject_ID
1      reflux      A21, A23
2 stomachache A21, A22, A23
```